# How to set div overflow property inside a display:flex element

Tags: css, flexbox, overflow

So I have this calendar app that I'm creating using flexbox property... the problem is that I don't have much experience with that property and things are not working as expected.

So in this example I have a header, a div with `flex: 1` and a footer.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex: 1;
}
.container > div {
    overflow: scroll;
    height: 120px;
    padding: 10px;
}
header, footer {
    background: darkslateblue;
    color: white;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
    <header>lol</header>

    <div class="container">
        <div>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br></div>            
        <div>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br></div>            
        <div>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br></div>            
        <div>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br></div>            
        <div>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br></div>            
        <div>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br></div>            
        <div>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br></div>            
        <div>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br></div>            
    </div>

    <footer>foo bar</footer>
```

I want the middle div to span all the space of the page except for header and footer, as expected by the `flex: 1` property.

BUT...

I also want the children divs to have `overflow-y: auto` and to not push the height outside of boundaries. So the divs should have height equivalent to the parent div divided by the amount of divs, without me having to hardcode a value to the height of the child divs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add height and overflow to body, then overflow to the middle container too.

It might be wised to set a min-height to body or remove it on small screens.

flex can be inbricated.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height:100vh;
    min-height:35em; /* or whatever value seem fine to you*/
}
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex: 1;
    overflow:auto;
}
.container > div {
    overflow: scroll;
    /*height: 120px;*/
    flex:1;
    padding: 10px;
}
header, footer {
    background: darkslateblue;
    color: white;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<header>lol</header>

    <div class="container">
        <div>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br></div>            
        <div>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br></div>            
        <div>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br></div>            
        <div>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br></div>            
        <div>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br></div>            
        <div>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br></div>            
        <div>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br></div>            
        <div>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br>dummy text<br></div>            
    </div>

    <footer>foo bar</footer>
```